# Smarty: special characters get changed unwanted- utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, smarty

I've data with special characters (french accent grave). When I select with php script and output (print) it looks fine. When I pass to Smarty the characters get changed. My html has follwoing setting: 
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
Not sure what's missing or incorrect?

gr, Patrick

Comment: In the browser, View -> Character encoding, does it recognize the utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Maybe your server sends a content-type header. HTTP headers have precedence over HTML meta tags.

Comment: When you open the smarty file with Notepad++, what do you see to the lower right? You should see "ANSI as UTF-8". By the way, do you `|escape`? In that case, you should supply the second parameter to it: `{$var|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}` as per http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the beginning of yours php file and check:

// utf-8

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// mbstring UTF8 coding (optional)

mb_detect_order(array('UTF-8', 'ASCII'));
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');